# MetaTrader 4 on Mac OS X combined with C++ or R

Tags: c++, r, algorithmic-trading, metatrader4, mql4

I am on a Mac (OS X 10.9.1) and looking to combine **`Metatrader 4`** with a **`C++`** data processing program of my own. This program will take market information from my `Metatrader` and send back signals for specific instruments.

I have tested the `C++` program on its own, by listening to data on a socket published by a Python program. The easiest for me would be to publish and listen to the socket from `Metatrader` (is this possible?) using **`mql4`**.

Alternatively, I am willing to send data and poll for signals, using a `DLL`-like interface. `DLL`s are windows specific, so how can one set something similar (e.g. `.dylib`) up on a Mac and is that even possible to use from `Metatrader`? If not possible, is it possible to use a windows `DLL` through a `wineskin` ?

If anyone has a better suggestion, I am definitely open to changing plans (I also have the code in **`R`** and **`Java`**).

Comment: On Mac there are some dll's ?

Comment: There are `dylib` files which do the same thing.

Comment: There is a possibility to include dylib to mq4 file ? Maybe there is..

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to use a socket connection from mql4 ?

Comment: http://codebase.mql4.com/6831 maybe helps you ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Designing a serious trading infrastructure, your needs would be well if not best met by a neutral messaging layer. This alowed me to operate a **cluster-based computing** communicating massively parallel with a crowd of **MT4** nodes.

Yes, MT4 can not only publish a low-level <*socket*> it can belong to a more complex "*Scaleable Formal Cummunication Framework*" in a very intelligent manner.

Do you wish to have a **CLI-interface to command your MT4 nodes** -- selectively, with a syntax & grammar of CLI-instructions ( not speaking about test-automation et al ...)?

Do you wish to have a central <***syslog***> daemon to off-load HFT-traffic loaded MT4 node(s) and automate + administer scripted monitoring & maintenance tasks?

Do you wish to have an external **GPU-computing engine/cluster** to communicate in a Client/Server manner with MT4 EA on a per-tickEvent basis?

**ZeroMQ** and/or **nanomsg** frameworks will allow you to design and develop many-to-many ( node-network-wise ) & any-to-any ( implementation language-wise ) systems.

MT4/MQL4 has a direct smart wrapper for ZeroMQ >>> thanks to Austen Conrad on GitHub **MQL4ZMQ**

**ZeroMQ** >>> thanks to it's great team has many language bindings - C/C++, Python, **Java**, **R**, Erlang, ..

so your Project may start on rock solid grounds & independent of any particular architecture gridlocks ( DLL moving sands et al )

Engineering built-ins save you a lot of time and efforts and avoid re-inventing wheel

Comment: ZeroMQ was definitely the way to go. Thanks!